# Any neuroscience related intelligence theories?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, intelligence, experimental-neuroscience

Correlations between biological measurements and intelligence has been made in the past, e.g. blood flow or metrics like cortex size, though are there any specific neuroscience related intelligence theories and if so, any sources?

With theories I’m referring to works like the psychometric ones (Spearman) or cognitive-contextual like Triarchic and so forth..
Are any well-researched theories in the neuroscience space?